# Lock graphice object in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, drawimage

it seems to be very stupid question, but I really need a help, I'm making a task with drawing a background transparent gradient image and then draw some objects over it, the problem is I want to draw this image once but the other objects will be drawn multi time to perform some animation

the code is as following, this is the code that i want to run once, and I have created a boolen variable = false and then set it to true

```
public void drawLockLayer(Graphics g) {
        try {
            lock = Image.createImage(Paths.lock);
            g.drawImage(lock, 0, 0, LGBMainMidlet.width, LGBMainMidlet.height);
            System.out.println("After Draw Image");
            drawOnce = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

other code is as following

```
public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {

        synchronized (g) {
            if (drawOnce == false) {
                drawLockLayer(g);
            }
        }
        pos = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() % 2700) / 300);

        int i = 0;

        g.setColor(bgColor);
        g.fillRoundRect(startX, startY, width, height, 20, 20);


        g.setColor(fgColor);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(loadMsg, startX + (spacing / 4), startY + (spacing / 4));

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                int thickness = 6;
                if (i == pos) {
                    thickness = 14;
                } else if (i == pos - 1) {
                    thickness = 10;
                }
                g.fillRect((startX + x * spacing - (thickness / 2)) + (width / 3), (startY + y * spacing - (thickness / 2)) + (height / 3), thickness, thickness);
                i++;
            }
        }


    }
```

it is enter the method but it is not draw the background image , What I want to do is to lock the graphics object until he finish drawing the image then continue with other code

can anyone help please

Comment: you might want to add the code that declares and initializes variables.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues with the code:

- synchronizing on a Graphics is generally a bad idea
- paint is only supposed to be called from one thread. are you sure it isn't and you actually need to synchronize? where does rect come from?
- to make it easier to maintain, you should set drawOnce to true in paint()

Comment: synchronizing : I was trying to make it done 
I need to run it in another thread as my main thread is working to load some data from web service
I have tried to use it in several places but it does not work

Comment: This answer is correct drawing in LWUIT/Codename One is always single threaded. Amira, I suggest you read the developer guide in LWUIT or Codename One and just use a background image style.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set drawOnce to false before calling paint.

It looks like your code is based on GameCanvas. What do you think of the below approach?

```
    class MainCanvas extends GameCanvas {

    // rect is an attribute

    private void updateScreen() {
        drawOnce = false;
        paint(getGraphics(), rect);
    }

    public void start() {
        new DataThread().start();
        new AnimationThread().start();
    }

    class DataThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (/*IO stuff not done*/) {
                // save data
                updateScreen();
            }
        }
    }

    class AnimationThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (/*IO stuff not done*/) {
                // sleep a little
                updateScreen();
            }
        }
    }

    // drawLockLayer and paint(Graphics, Rectangle) methods

    } // end of MainCanvas class
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the lwuit tag on the question.